# Editing system settings not working

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, sound, brightness, system-settings

So this happened after I tried to plug an external monitor into a 10,1 Macbook Pro running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

I first started playing with nvidia-settings without success and then I tried to install xephyr to check if lightdm would change something.

But after the reboot, the Ubuntu control settings a.k.a sound, brightness, even other languages key mappings stopped responding to editing changes. 
For example, if I change the speed of the mouse pointer it has no actual effect on the configuration.

I have no experience with the problem and have found no thread speaking of what could be the root cause of it so I thought it useful to create one.